# Best way to set up Laravel with dev

Tags: php, laravel

We have just taken the plunge at work and decided to use Laravel on all future large developments. We are currently discussing how we should set variables for `dev`, `testing` and `live`. On my own personal projects I have things like:

```
if(strpos(__FILE__,'/live/')) {
    $currentEnv = 'live';
} else { ... }
```

I then set variables off the back of `$currentEnv`. Laravel recommends using a 
custom `.env` file in the root of each of your installs *(which I presume means it's out side of version control)*.

Can someone please tell me the merits and pitfalls of each approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **.env file** is the settings of your application you can configure your default environment variable check the following content sample:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=AMpO3aZSVYhYKIAQyKch3G0efT3xGrve

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=test

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

> If you want to work locally you can set:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

> In Production you can set:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Answer (score 1):

using .env make sense, you can put anything you want there, and then use env() to get a value from the .env file.

yes the .env file is out of version control.
you can also create .env.testing for your testing environment

you can also modify the default configs on the config/ directory, or add new one, and use Config to retrieve these values.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-env