# Cant query in Using Laravel 5.2 at MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, laravel

I have this error. I searched at google for some possible solution and followed some steps but still I still get this error.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

My .env looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

when I test my data source (ODBC) I get successful connection. But when I try to query at my program. I have this error. BTW I'm using Laravel 5.2 and MSSQL 2008 R2.

The database in installed locally.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Comment: @DenStudent I've already tried that solution and I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you using homestead? wamp? is the db located at local machine or remotely? How does your .env file look like?

Comment: @henrik my database is located locally.

Comment: You answered 1 out of 4 questions, If you want to get help, you need to provide more details. It's impossible to help you if we don't get the full context.

Comment: @henrik I've edited my question I included there my .env then Im not using wamp I run it directly using php artisan command