# Connecting to MySQL from Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant

I set up a database called `cms` which I can connect to if I `ssh` as the root user and I can manipulate the database just fine. I also can connect with MySQL Workbench. However, when it comes to connecting through Laravel 5.4, it will not let me connect to MySQL to run a migration. I have the same credentials in my `.env` file as I do in MySQL Workbench, but still no connection. Any ideas?

Below is what I have in my `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: ` [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: Check this if you use Homestead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Comment: Tried `DB_HOST=localhost` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried multiple setting and nothing.

Comment: @jesders88, it won't work without a password in the remote context, please see the answer below....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via SSH you are able to connect to MySQL as root without a password, because that is the default behavior. It allows the local Linux `root` user to login as `root` on MySQL with no password.

When you want to connect not locally (via SSH) but instead via TCP/IP or a socket using the PHP mysql library, then you need to setup a user for that.

Here is how to do it:

1) Log in via SSH as you normally did, and with root access MySQL

2) Create a user:

```
CREATE USER 'laravel'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ENTER-PASSWORD-HERE';
```

3) Grant permissions to that user on your database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON cms.* TO 'laravel'@'%';
```

4) Flush permissions so that everything reloads:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

5) Now exit SSH and edit your .env file like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cms
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=ENTER-PASSWORD-HERE
```

Of course, please change the placeholder "ENTER-PASSWORD-HERE" to something of your preference.

You should now be able to connect from your application.

Comment: Perfect. I can connect over ssh so this seems like it will do the trick.

Comment: Correction, 

For some reason I still have the same issue.
`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cms and
   table_name = migrations)`

` [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: Side Note: I am trying to connect to the database from outside of vagrant if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well, in that case, your DB_HOST is definitely not going to be `127.0.0.1`. If you are using Homestead, try with: 192.168.10.10, if not then login into your VM with ssh and run: `sudo netstat -natp | grep mysql` to see if MySQl is listening; and then `ifconfig` to identify the IP.

Comment: If homestead, your port will most likely be: `33060`, but you can see that with the `netstat` command detailed above.

Comment: Actually, it seems you can try with :  127.0.0.1, and port 33060 as per:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#connecting-to-databases

Comment: Not using homestead. What am I looking for in the netstat and ifconfig?

Comment: Can you open a new question? This a separate issue from the one in your original post. I will answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981838/connecting-to-mysql-outside-of-vagrant-box