# Connecting to MySQL outside of Vagrant box

Tags: php, mysql, linux, vagrant, virtual-machine

I tried to `sudo netstat -natp | grep mysql` to see what port mysql was listening on and I see that it is actually listening on what is below. I also did an `ifconfig` to see what ip I was on within the vagrant box. I am trying to find out this info so that I can connect to a mysql database through a vagrant virtual machine, but use that information in an .env inside of a laravel application that is outside of the box. Can anyone help?

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LIST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /etc/my.cnf, make ensure you have the following configuration:

1) Comment out this line if it's present, as it prevents external access

```
#skip-networking
```

2) Set bind-address to as follows, if set to locahost, only local connections will be possible:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

3) Restart MySQL with:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

This should do it.

If it doesn't then you may have a firewall consideration to take care of. If you're on the default iptables, then run:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

To verify the port is open, from your external host (not the VM) you can run:

```
nmap <vm-ip-address-here>
```

If you don't see 3306 open, you have other uncommon networking issues.

Comment: Also make sure that in your `.env` file, you set the IP address of the VM, not 127.0.0.1. Likely it will be in the `192.168.x.x` range

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for your help. We'll see if this gets me somewhere