# Laravel 5.7 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am using laravel 5.7 and i am getting this error. But its working fine for older versions. i am using xamp with php 7.3.* . Here is my code

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DEFAULT=mysql
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3308'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'project'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'default' => env('DB_DEFAULT', 'mysql')
        ],
```

Database is fine and i tried connecting with test.php file, its connecting fine but have problem with laravel 5.7

[image]

Comment: Remove your port from `DB_HOST=localhost:3308`.

Comment: @Marwelln still same issue

Comment: Have you tried with the solutions provided in this post? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Comment: have you changed _mysql_ port from 3306 to 3308?

Comment: For future posts it would be helpful if you paste the full error code instead of a screenshot

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Yes i changed the port from 3306 to 3308 intentionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research about laravel 5.7 and xamp, i found the solution. It was basically the cache issue in the file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` .

It was reading this config cache file instead of my new file. I removed it and not its working fine. I am very thankful all of you.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means the target machine was reachable, but is not listening on that port.

Some things to check:

- The default port for MySQL is 3306, not 3308. Was this change intentional?
- XAMPP often requires that you start the database manually. Is it online?
- If the database is on your local machine, is it also configured to listen on 3308 instead of 3306 like your Laravel code?
- Make sure your config isn't cached: `php artisan config:clear`

If the database is not on your local machine, then it could easily be a firewall setting causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah i changed the port intentionally and my database was online .

Comment: @MahaDev but is MySQL *listening* on port 3308 as well?

Comment: Yes, the issue was in config file. I answered my question, Please check . and yes, thanks for you answer and efforts. I am up-voting it :)

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP to check your PORT number then change DB_PORT. I hope it works

[image]

[image]