# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from `categories`)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to load categories from db to index page but it says:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from `categories`)

controller:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Index;
  use App\Category;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

      public function index()
      {
          $categories = Category::all();
          return view('index', comapct('categories'));
      }
```

index blade:

```
  @foreach($categories as $category)
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-02.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Share more details please. Are you using a Mac or Windows? which development  environment you're using Wamp, Homestead, or valet .. etc? It's not code-related issue I believe.

Comment: m using windows 10 ,,, xampp ,,, phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? Can you perform the same query from a remote machine from another source (CLI)?

This is an issue accessing the database host, not with the code (necessarily).

Comment: m using phpmyadmin at windows10

Comment: I cant perform it on another source

Comment: Check your connectivity from another machine to the database. If this is using MySQL, by default it will reject connections that do not come from localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

"Actively refused it" means that the host sent a reset instead of an ack when you tried to connect. It is therefore not a problem in your code. Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port, this may be because it is not running at all or because it is listening on a different port.

Comment: this link will help you click here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Comment: You must change this file: "C:\wamp\bin\mysql[mysql_version]\my.ini" For example: "C:\wamp\bin\mysql[mysql5.6.12]\my.ini"

And change default port 3306 to 80. (Lines 20 & 27, in both) port = 3306 To port = 80

you tried this

Comment: I changed

DB_HOST=localhost

to

DB_HOST=localhost:3307

in .env file  or try this

Comment: Restart Your apche & mysql.

Comment: I just restart my whole system by changing things to default now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Clear all caches:

```
 1. php artisan config:clear 
 2. php artisan route:cache  
 3. php artisan route:cache
 4. php artisan cache:clear
 5. php artisan view:clear
```

If still proceeds do restart Apache and SQL server