# Model in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5

How to fix this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.

```
SQL: insert into `developers` (`name`, `dept`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hany, mobile web, 2019-09-18 18:35:33, 2019-09-18 18:35:33)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please create a minimal example of what you are trying to do to help us better understand the problem.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Laravel: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref)