# Laravel 7 check database connection status and show custom error

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, connection, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel-7 and MySQL SERVER for my project. How can I get the status of DB connection?
I have already tried few methods, but it did not work. I want to get the status and display the custom success or error status.

My code is below:

```
        try{
            DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
            return redirect('/registration')->with('db_con_status','Database connected!');

        }catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $dbexp){
            return redirect('/registration')->with('db_con_error',$dbexp->getMessage());
        }
```

but it still shown Laravel in-built ignition error like...

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = abc@xyz.com)

How to catch that exception and handle it?

Comment: Are you sure mysql(in wamp or xamp) is started?

Comment: Run this and try again: `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Laravel: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514241/php-laravel-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref)

Comment: Yes ParisaN, I manually stoped the XAMPP MySQL. Because I want to handle the DB exception and display the custom error or success message.

Comment: Do you want to apply handler class instead of `try-catch`?

Comment: Yes, try-catch does not work, so if it's possible by Handler class, kindly give me the solution. How to do that using handler class, I'am new in laravel.

Comment: Your code has not problem. Set DB_HOST=localhost to DB_HOST=localhost:3307 in .env file. Check your connectivity from another machine to the database. This may be because it is listening on a different port.

Comment: My problem is solved. There was an issue with my code written sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xamp is running in background. Open task manager and stop it from there (if you use windows).

Comment: No, it's does not matter that XAMPP running or not, I already told that I manually stoped the XAMPP server for execution and handle the custom DB con errors, it's my simple question.